# Angular http request and redirect

Tags: angular, http

I have a `button` and when i click on the button angular makes http request to the server and redirect to `'/'`. I do it with `this.router.navigateByUrl('/');` where `router: Router`. I cant use `routerLink` because i make request to the server, and if response will be `error`, button shouldnt redirect to `'/'`. And when i redirect to `'/'` angular should make a request to the server, i wrote this logic in `DoCheck()` of component, i didnt find another way out. And when i redirect to `'/'` `DoCheck()` triggers thrice so angular makes three requests to the server instead of one. I tried to write the logic in `OnInit()` and `OnChange()`, but in doesnt work, angular makes no request when i redirect to `'/'`. May be i'm doing wrong. Please help me. Thanks

```
  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.isLogged === false) {
      if (this.cookies.get('userHashCode')) {
        let hash: Hash = {
          name: this.cookies.get('userHashCode')
        }
        this.serverSide.getUserByHashCode('/getUserByHashCode', hash).subscribe(user => {
          this.isLogged = true;
          console.log(user);
        }, error => console.log(error));
      }
    }

  }
```

when button is clicked

```
this.serverSide.reg('/reg', user).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.cookies.put('userHashCode', user.hash);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      }, error => console.log(error));
```

`serverSide.reg` and `serverSide.getUserByHashCode` just make `http.post` request.

this is `'/regist'` path

```
<div class="w-25 mx-auto">
  <span class="text-danger text-center my-2">{{message}}</span>
  <input #login type="text" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Login">
  <input #email type="email" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Email">
  <input #password type="password" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Password">
  <input #password2 type="password" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Repeat password">
  <input (click)="onRegist(login.value, email.value, password.value, password2.value)" type="button" class="my-2 float-right btn btn-outline-primary" value="To register">
</div>


onRegist(login: string, email: string, password: string, password2: string): void {
    this.message = '';
    if (this.checkLogin(login) && this.checkEmail(email) && this.checkPassword(password) && password === password2) {
      let user: User = {
        login: login,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        hash: sha1(login + password).toString()
      }
      this.serverSide.reg('/reg', user).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.cookies.put('userHashCode', user.hash);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      }, error => console.log(error));
    } else {
      this.message = "incorrect inputs";
    }
  }
```

`'/'`

```
<div *ngIf="!isLogged" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button routerLink="/login" class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0 mx-2">Log in</button>
      <button routerLink="/regist" class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div dropdown *ngIf="isLogged" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 dropdown">
      <button dropdownToggle class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0 mx-2 dropdown-toggle">{{login}}</button>
      <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/settings">Settings</li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">Account</li>
        <li class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Log out</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ServerSideService } from './server-side.service';
import { Hash } from "./interfaces/hash";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isLogged: boolean;
  login: string;

  constructor(
    private cookies: CookieService,
    private router: Router,
    private serverSide: ServerSideService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLogged = false;
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.isLogged === false) {
      if (this.cookies.get('userHashCode')) {
        let hash: Hash = {
          name: this.cookies.get('userHashCode')
        }
        this.serverSide.getUserByHashCode('/getUserByHashCode', hash).subscribe(user => {
          this.isLogged = true;
          console.log(user);
        }, error => console.log(error));
      }
    }

  }

  getQuery(query: string): void {
    if (query.length > 0) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(`/search/${query}`);
    }
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.cookies.removeAll();
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/`);
  }
}


export class ServerSideService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  reg(url: string, user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, user);
  }

  getUserByHashCode(url: string, hash: Hash): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, hash);
  }

  auth(url: string, user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, user);
  }
}
```

routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LogInComponent },
  { path: 'regist', component: RegistComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: ProfileSettingsComponent },
  { path: 'search/:query', component: SearchListComponent }
]
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code for your question. It is very unlikely that your question will be answerable without seeing your code. Also the DoCheck() method is a very heavy function and should be avoided in almost all cases.

Comment: @Narm i dont know what should i use instead of `DoCheck()`. Code added

Comment: I am having a difficult time understanding your question. Is the problem you're having is that when you select the button in your component your http.post requests fails and your app also fails to reroute to the root route "/" ?

Comment: @Narm noo, no fails with requests, everythink is work. The problem is that angular makes three requests instead of one, when i redirect to `'/'`. I know, it's beacuse of i'm usign `DoCheck()`. What should i use instead of? That is the question

Comment: Ok great, now we're getting somewhere. Can you show the full component code and html template for the component that currently contains the button and docheck()?

Comment: @Narm sure......

Comment: Have you tried ngAfterViewInit() instead of ngDoCheck(). ngAfterViewInit() is invoked once.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 it doesnt work, because it triggers after `OnInit`. When i redirect, component no re-created. Maybe is there right way to redirect with calling `OnInit()` or `OnChange()` or `AfterViewInit()` , but in my case it doesnt trigger. It works only with `DoCheck()`, in my case

Comment: @epsilon Which angular version you are using

Comment: @ranjeet8082 lastest 5.2.8

Comment: @epsilon Ideally ngOnInit should run on navigation. Can you check on other browsers.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 i have tried in firefox and there is the same problem

Comment: Notice that ngDoCheck gets called with a high frequency, so its strongly adviced to use sync. quick operations on it. So the logic currently in it its already way to complex...